# Dynamicaly Changing the  <textarea > size,style

Tags: javascript, html, coding-style, size, textarea

How can i change the   field size diynamicaly? 
I have a select field and there are 3 options with different values. 
So if the user selects one of them in the   you see the values.
But how can i change the   size that the values from option field fits in the

```
function changeText()
        {

            var select       = document.getElementById("surl");
            var textfield    = document.getElementById("turl");
            var bold         = document.getElementById("burl");
            var link         = document.getElementById("linkText");

            if(bold.style.display == "none")
                bold.style.display = "";
           //if(link.innerHtml)

            bold.innerHtml   = select.value;
            //if(link.innerHTML !="")
               link.innerHTML= select.value;
            textfield.value  = select.value;

        }


<b>Sample: </b><select id="surl" onchange="changeText();" style="visibility: visible;" name="linkText">
         <option>Select LinkText</option>
         <option value="<a href='http://www.doesntexist.dsdsd/'>Want sign? http://www.doesntexist.dsdsd</a>">
            Variant1 
         </option>
          <option value="<a href='http://www.doesntexist.dsdsd/'>Wanna killme? http://www.doesntexist.dsdsd</a>">
            Variant 2
         </option>


     </select>
     <br />
    <div class="succes">
     <span id="burl" style="display: none"><br /><a id="linkText" href="http://www.doesntexist/"></a></span>
     </div>
     </p>
     <p>

         <textarea  id="turl" style="">
        <a  href="http://www.doesntexist">text...</a>
      </textarea>
     </p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I must’ve misunderstood your problem.

So you want to resize a textarea dynamically based on what, its contents? You could use the [jQuery autoResize plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/) for this…

Answer (score 1):

A quick 'n' dirty jQuery solution would be the following:

```
$('input#foo-option-1').bind('change, click', function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('textarea').css('height', '150px');
 }
});

$('input#foo-option-2').bind('change, click', function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('textarea').css('height', '250px');
 }
});

$('input#foo-option-3').bind('change, click', function() {
 if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
   $('textarea').css('height', '350px');
 }
});
```

Of course, this code isn’t very DRY. Moreover, modifying CSS properties through JavaScript is never a very good idea — it’s better to add classes dynamically through JS and specify the actual CSS in your CSS files (duh).

Comment: That was not what im looking for and the code looks like spaghetti wit tomato sauce

Comment: @streetparade > that was rude

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("textarea_id").style.width = "300px";
document.getElementById("textarea_id").style.width = "200px";
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, the question was updated. Seconding @Mathias Bynens' answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i thought there are more devs who can help; any way here is the answer

**first create a function which calculates the strlen**

```
function strlen(strVar)
{
   return(strVar.length)
}
```

**Second create a var tfcount**

```
var tfcount      = strlen(select.value);
```

**and finaly**

```
textfield.style.width   =  tfcount < 110 ? tfcount = 110 : 3.5*tfcount+"px";
textfield.style.height  =  tfcount < 110 ? tfcount = 110 : tfcount/2.5+"px";
```

Comment: This isn’t an answer to his question. OP wants to resize a textarea based on which radio button is selected, not on the textarea’s contents.

Comment: First the above question has no where a radio button. Their is a select field with several option fields. And the above answer does exactly what the question was resizing a text area dynamicaly.